# Swipeitem doesnt work when open the app and press the button

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The swipeview doesnt work when I open the app and press accept button but it works after when I open and close the detail page.

xaml shows list of events from sql and show swipeitem

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="eventview"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectionChanged="eventview_SelectionChanged"
                            EmptyView="No Pending events">
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close">
                                    <SwipeItem Text="Decline" BackgroundColor="red"/>
                                    <SwipeItem Text="Accept" BackgroundColor="Green" Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked"/>
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems> 
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding stats}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                
                            </Grid>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

cs  shows click on the item that will open detail page and when click on the swipeitem

```
        private async void eventview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lastSelection = e.CurrentSelection[0] as Event;
            var eventss = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Event;
           var eventpage = new Eventdetailpage();
           eventpage.BindingContext = eventss;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(eventpage);

        } 
        private async void SwipeItem_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lastSelection != null)
            {
                lastSelection.stats = "Accepted";
                await App.Database.UpdateventAysnc(lastSelection);
                eventview.ItemsSource = await App.Database.querypendingevent();
                accpetedevents.ItemsSource = await App.Database.queryacceptevent();
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is a LOT of missing context here, but I'm going to guess that when you first open the app `lastSelection` is null, so the `if` statement is never executed

Comment: @Jason thats right

Comment: you should be able to get the current item from the `sender`'s `BindingContext`

Comment: @Jason how do I do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `lastSelection` is null, then your `if` won't execute and nothing will happen

you should be able to get the current item from the `sender`'s `BindingContext`

```
var item = (SwipeItem)sender;
lastSelection = (Event)item.BindingContext;
```